# Why is the average magnitude of the imaginary parts of the roots of these polynomials greater than that of the real part?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, asymptotics, roots

Let $f_n(x)$ be a polynomial obtained by replacing $10$ with $x$ in the base $10$ expansion of $n, n \ge 10$. Eg. $f_{98}(x) = 9x+8$ and $f_{2021}(x) = 2x^3 + 2x + 1$. $f_n(x)$ has exactly $[k = \log_{10}n]$ roots each comprising of its real and imaginary parts, either of which can be zero. We call $f_n(x)$  as the characteristic polynomial of $n$ since $f_n(10) = n$.

I was comparing the average the magnitude or the absolute value of the real part of the roots of $f_n(x)$ to that of the imaginary parts. My naïve expectation was that they should be equal. However data suggests otherwise.

[image]

For $n \le 10^4$, I computed all the roots for the roots of $f_n(x)$; there are $28683$ roots in total since for $n \ge 100, f_n(x)$ has multiple roots. I plotted the graph of the average magnitude of the real parts and the imaginary parts. After around the $23700$-th root, average of the real part falls below that of the real part and the seems to indicate no hope of a recovery.

**Question**: Is there any reason why beyond a certain point, the average magnitude of the imaginary parts of the roots of the characteristic polynomial should be greater than that of the real part?